# Concat multiple columns in separate cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a very simple table of three columns:
[image: table]

I need to concat two of them (B and C) in separate cells like this:
desired result
[image: desired result]

I tried this formula: `==TEXTJOIN("-";TRUE;B1:C5)` which does its work, but not the desired result. Please see the screenshot. The "D" column is what I get, and the "E" column is what I need to have:
What I get:
[image: what i get]

How do I achieve concatenating data of my columns in separate cells? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`=ArrayFormula(IF(B:B <> "",B:B&"-"&C:C,""))`

It will populate the row with the [string concatenation operand](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093592) `&` (same as `CONCAT()`) dynamically, and if the B cell is empty it will leave an empty cell.

[image]

If you by any means have a table header, you can always have the range go from `B2:B`, having the formula like this:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B <> "",B2:B&"-"&C2:C,""))`